# Most efficient way to retrieve rows of related data: subquery, or separate query with GROUP BY?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a very simple PostgreSQL query to retrieve the latest 50 news articles:

```
SELECT id, headline, author_name, body 
 FROM news 
 ORDER BY publish_date DESC 
 LIMIT 50
```

Now I also want to retrieve the latest 10 comments for each article as well. I can think of two ways to accomplish retrieving them and I'm not sure which one is best in the context of PostgreSQL:

---

**Option 1:**

Do a subquery directly for the comments in the original query and cast the result to an array:

```
SELECT headline, author_name, body,
  ARRAY(
   SELECT id, message, author_name,
     FROM news_comments
     WHERE news_id = n.id
     ORDER BY DATE DESC
     LIMIT 10
  ) AS comments
 FROM news n
 ORDER BY publish_date DESC 
 LIMIT 50
```

Obviously, in this case, application logic would need to be aware of which index in the array is which column, that's no problem.

The one problem I see with the method is not knowing how the query planner would execute it. Would this effectively turn into 51 queries?

---

**Option 2:**

Use the original very simple query:

```
SELECT id, headline, author_name, body 
 FROM news 
 ORDER BY publish_date DESC 
 LIMIT 50
```

Then via application logic, gather all of the news ids and use those in a separate query, row_number() would have to be used here in order to limit the number of results per news article:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER(
            PARTITION BY author_id
            ORDER BY author_id DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM news_comment
          WHERE news_id IN(123, 456, 789)
    ) s
) s
where rn <= 10
```

This approach is obviously more complicated, and I'm not sure if this would have to retrieve *all* comments for the scoped news articles first, then chop off the ones where the row count is great than 10.

---

Which option is best? Or is there an even better solution I have overlooked?

For context, this is a news aggregator site I've developed myself, I currently have about 40,000 news articles across several categories, with about 500,000 comments, so I'm looking for the best solution to help me keep growing.

Comment: See the query plan generated for both set of queries and then decide

Comment: I agree with @Rahul. You need to look at the query plan, because the answer may greatly depend on what indexes are available. Ask the database what it intends to do, i.e. look at the query plan, then decide which plan looks better, or if you can improve it by other means.

Comment: The only sure way to tell: check the execution plan using `explain analyze`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should investigate execution plan for your statements using at least [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html). This will provide you with plan chosen by the optimizer while executing the statement itself and giving you back actual run times and other statistics as well.

Another solution would be to use [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) subquery to retrieve 10 comments for each news in separate rows, but then again - you need to investigate and compare plans to choose the best approach that works for you:

```
SELECT 
  n.id, n.headline, n.uathor_name, n.body, 
  c.id, c.message, c.author_name
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( 
  SELECT id, message, author_name
  FROM news_comments nc
  WHERE n.id = nc.news_id
  ORDER BY nc.date DESC
  LIMIT 10
  ) c ON TRUE
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 50
```

When your query contains `LATERAL` cross-references for each row retrieved from *news* LATERAL is evaluated using the connection in `WHERE` clause. Thus making it a repeated execution and joining the information retrieved from it for each row from your source table *news*.

This approach would save the time needed for your application logic to deal with arrays coming out from *option 1* while not having to issue many separate queries for each news like in *option 2* saving you (in this case) time needed to open separate transactions, establish connections, retrieve rows etc...

It would be good to look for performance improvements by creating indexes and looking into planner cost constans and planner method configuration parameters that you can experiment with to understand the choice planner has made. More on the subject [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html).

Comment: I ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE on all of the options, and the JOIN LATERAL was by far the fastest across a test of 20 million records with the correct indexes.